# Cannot access database using server explorer in visual studios

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I'm building my first MVC3 website and have connected my site to a mdf database file and created 3 controllers for them ( using enitity framework ).

When I run my site I can create and delete records from the tables, but when I try to access the tables through visual studios it says the tables are all empty.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong ?

( I need to access this database this way because there seems to be some records not showing up correctly and I want to empty the tables so I can start fresh )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't looking at the same database that the application is. Check your web.config to see what database + server instance (e.g. .\sqlexpress) that it's using.

From there you should be able to open that database and clean out. Alternatively you could change the connectionstring to point to the other database you are looking at from Visual Studio.

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right! Could it be visual studios copied the database ? I have 2 projects in my solution, 1 for my model stuff and one for views and controllers, I only remember creating it for the model project.